# How to add self-defined encryption algorithm into HTTPS stack?

Tags: encryption, ssl, https, openssl

I want to use HTTPS in a secure application, but replacing the symmetric encryption algorithm into a self-defined one.

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this goal. Is it possible to replace the relevant library to a self-defined one? For example, using OpenSSL?

To be more specific, in the first stage, I need to do it on win32 platform, could anyone tell me how to begin?

Comment: Do you have a target application you want to use this for? (Either way, this is likely to be a difficult task...)

Comment: @Bruno: Understanding TLS and the source code of most implementations is tricky, but inserting an already implemented symmetric cipher into an open source TLS library might be doable as SSL/TLS is designed for extensibility. Of course, it would again be tricky to fit the algorithm in the TLS library. Not that you would want to put it into production code, but that's more for security reasons...

Comment: @owlstead, agreed, I was just thinking it would make more sense to try to extend the lib used by the target app (e.g. libnss for Firefox) instead of extending a lib that may not be the one already used by the target app and then somehow bridging the two APIs (if possible). For example, extending OpenSSL and then trying to use it within FF would require extra work. I'm not sure the OP realises different apps are likely to use libs with APIs that are not necessarily compatible with each other. Understanding where the lib fits into the app would be a pre-requisite for customising such a lib.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Even if the operating system, the network stack, or your programming framework provides SSL/TLS functionality you can simply open a regular TCP connection and then communicate SSL encrypted using your own library.

Therefor the **answer is yes** - always and on every platform which supports regular TCP connections.

Comment: How to do that? For example, on win32 platform, internet explorer or firefox, how to do that?

Comment: @ciphor: Seems like your question was a bit imprecise. As we are here on Stackoverflow I have assumed we are talking about a custom application you are implementing. You never said something about patching the SSL implementation of an existing OS or application. That depends on the specific APIs of the OS/app.

Comment: Yes, I admit that my question is inaccurate. To be more specific, I want to patching the SSL implementation on win32 platform. Someone told me that I should looking at the win32 CSP (CryptoServiceProvider) interface. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think you can easily change win32 API's as those are closed source. OpenSSL or maybe OpenJDK (if you want slightly less hairy code) might be a better option. It's not a task for the weak of heart and it is likely to *reduce* cryptographic strength of the SSL channel by quite a big margin, as AES(-256) provides lots of security in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - you need to create a client and server that implement the SSL protocol. SSL uses cipher suites to communicate the algorithms to be used in the protocol, and you could define your own one.

From the TLS specifications (TLS 1.0, but I asume this hasn't changed) :

"All cipher suites whose first byte is 0xFF are considered private and can be used for defining local/experimental algorithms. Interoperability of such types is a local matter."

Use an open source library (preferably one with readable source) and change that.

As said in the comment, defining your own protocol/algorithm is very likely to severely impact security of SSL/TLS.